# Prevent .slideUp from setting display:none on complete

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I can prevent an element from changing to display:none once the .slideUp function is complete?

I'd like for the function to stop once it reaches the min-hight of the div if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use $.animate on the height property.

```
$('#myelement').animate({ height: 0 }, { duration: 'slow' });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sZX2s/

Comment: Ah that's far easier then. Thank you!

Comment: you could also animate to height: $('#myelement').css('minHeight').replace('px','') if you are specifying min-height in your css. http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/sZX2s/1/